# ReactでSoundJSを使う

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## 質問内容

Reactを使ってSoundJSを使いたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
また、音楽ファイルの読み込みにPreloadJSを使っています。
エラーの内容がよくわからないので教えていただけると幸いです。

Reactを使わない生JSでかくと動きます。

## エラー文

```
Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at S (index.js:1)
    at V (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at a (index.js:1)
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
```

## ソースコード

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const InputBox = styled.div``;

function init(){
  /* global createjs */
  var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
  queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
  var manifest = [
    {"src":"./music/test.mp3","id":"sound1"}
  ];
  queue.loadManifest(manifest,true);
  queue.addEventListener('fileload',handleFileLoad);
  queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);

  function handleFileLoad(event){
    var item = event.item;
    var type = item.type;

    if(createjs.Types.SOUND === type){
      startSound(item.id);
    }
  }
  function startSound(soundid){
    var instance = createjs.Sound.createInstance(soundid);
    instance.volume = 0.1;
    function doStop(){
      instance.stop();
    }
    function doPlay(){
      instance.play();
    }
    document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click',doStop);
    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click',doPlay);
  }
}
window.onload = function(){
  init();
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <InputBox>
          <input type="button" id="play" value="play"></input>
          <input type="button" id="stop" value="stop"></input>
        </InputBox>
      </span>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

音楽ファイルはindex.htmlからのパスでないといけないらしいです。